# Use Vue only in part of an existing jQuery project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an old project and I want to use Vue to make some fields of one of the forms be shown or hidden, I'm importing Vue from CDN and initializing a new Vue app, I've tried setting an id to the body of the project, but it does not work, then I created a div inside the body section wrapping all existing code, but the result is all the content is gone and gives a blank page. If i initialize Vue with the form id now the form is blank.

I've checked that Vue is imported adding a `console.log` in created lifecycle and it works, the problem is old content of page is missing when I wrap it with id specified in Vue initialization.

Here's my code:

```js
const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#my-form',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedProductType: "Producto 3x2 o 2x1",
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ CREATED");
  },
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body class="fixed-layout skin-blue-dark p-0" id="page-top" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
  <p>A LOT OF CONTENT HERE</p>
  <form action="" method="POST" class="form" id="my-form" data-action="create">
    
    <p>A LOT OF CONTENT HERE</p>
    <label for="name">Tipo de producto</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_type" id="product-type" v-model="selectedProductType" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona...</option>
            <option value="Producto con descuento">Producto con descuento</option>
            <option value="Producto 3x2 o 2x1">Producto 3x2 o 2x1</option>
            <option value="Producto en combo">Producto en combo</option>
            <option value="Producto no promocional">Producto no promocional</option>
        </select>
    <br>
                
    {{ selectedProductType }}
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried wrapping parts of code with different div IDs but it never works.
I want to know if it is possible to use Vue in my use case and how to achieve it.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:
I've added some code to current snippet, but I dont't know why it works in the snippet and not in my working code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use Vue like this. I did it before for part of a C# asp.net server side rendered website. I see you bind Vue with a form, could you please try wrapping your form with a div and bind like that?

Comment: Vue will replace the DOM node (and all of its children) where you bind it. Move the old form content inside Vue - as one or more components.

Comment: @IVOGELOV moving it will cause me to lose all the features already done.

Comment: I want vue to wrap my content without losing it.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: @Mansur I've tried with no success.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to include a runnable snippet. Could you please update it to explain what you're expecting to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: @Etheryte I was trying to put my code, but it working in the snipped as i expect, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the creation of the Vue component, and the div with the initialisation element id and the vue components tags.
The initialisation part of Vue looks good to me, just make sure to happen after the components are defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="fixed-layout skin-blue-dark p-0" id="page-top" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
  <p>A LOT OF CONTENT HERE</p>
  <div id="my-form">
    <my-form></my-form>
</div>

<script>
    
    Vue.component('my-form', {
        template:`
        <form action="" method="POST" class="form" id="my-form" data-action="create">
                <p>A LOT OF CONTENT HERE</p>
                <label for="name">Tipo de producto</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="product_type" id="product-type" v-model="selectedProductType" required>
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona...</option>
                  <option value="Producto con descuento">Producto con descuento</option>
                   <option value="Producto 3x2 o 2x1">Producto 3x2 o 2x1</option>
                   <option value="Producto en combo">Producto en combo</option>
                   <option value="Producto no promocional">Producto no promocional</option>
                 </select>
               <br>
                {{ selectedProductType }}
        </form>`,
        data() {
          return {
             selectedProductType: "Producto 3x2 o 2x1",
          }
        }
    })
    const vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#my-form',
        created(){
            console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ CREATED");
        }
    })

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

this should work!

Comment: I don't want to override the form, I just want to wrap it with vue to use some properties and conditions with the current elements, the form is reusable and has a lot of dependencies, thats why i'm not allowed to override it.

Comment: That way you're not overriding it you're wraping it, jquery should work normally there, but the vue variables should exist in a Vue component scope, you could also just wrap the selector if that's what you want. But shouldn't affect any thing you did around it.

Comment: I got it, I'll be trying to ensure it'll be the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`data(){return{}}` is needed when you are creating `Vue.component`, in case of `new Vue` you need `data:{}`

Try `data:{}` instead of `data(){return{}}` like this:

```js
const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#my-form',
  data: {
      selectedProductType: "Producto 3x2 o 2x1"
  }
})
```

Comment: @kissu ```data(){return{}}``` is needed when you are creating ```Vue.component```, in case of ```new Vue``` you need ```data:{}```, read the docs

Comment: It doesn't work with the return if it's a new Vue instance ?

Comment: It didn't work for me, i've seen that setting data as an object instead as a function doesn't keep reactivity working.

Comment: @JonathanArias can you share your code as single a HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed to set Vue in `head` section instead of the end of `body` tag, I added Vue from CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

And then, I initilized it after all components were loaded in the bottom of `body` tag.